# Single-line function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, dictionary

Can someone explain me how to write this function, which should return the `factorial` of x.

The way I tried to do it gives me an `error`.

This line is inside a dictionary and refers to *`Operation.UnaryOperation`* that is *`(Double) -> Double`*

I tried to write the function I need extensively, It should look like this:

```
    private func factorial(n: Double) -> Double {
    if (n<=1) {
        return 1
       }
    return n * factorial(n-1)
    }
```

Now I need to convert it to a single-line function, how do I do it? would it look something like this?, why am I getting an error?

```
"x!" : Operation.UnaryOperation({if ($0<=1) {return 1} else {return $0 * factorial($0-1)}}),
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What do you mean with "assign a name"? In what way? For what purpose?

Comment: I want to give a name to this function so that I can recall it inside the function itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just embed the named function in the closure - like this

```
enum Operation {
    case UnaryOperation( (Double) -> Double)
    case BinaryOperation( (Double, Double) -> Double)
}

let dictionary: [String: Operation] = [
    "+" : Operation.BinaryOperation({ return $0 + $1 }),
    "!" : Operation.UnaryOperation({
        arg: Double in
        func factorial(x: Double) -> Double {
            if x <= 1 {
                return 1
            } else {
                return x * factorial(x - 1)
            }
        }
        return factorial(arg)
    })
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this solved it! anyway why do I need to use the "arg in" for it to work?

Comment: You don't - I just expanded the closure for clarity. You can drop `arg in` and replace `factorial(arg)` with `factorial($0)`. It's a preference of mine not to use `$n` syntax in anything longer than a one-liner.

Comment: If it really has to be single-line, try `Operation.UnaryOperation({ func f(x: Double) -> Double {return x<=1 ? 1 : x * f(x - 1)}; return f($0)})` :)
... not so readable...

Comment: No it has not to be single line, I prefer it in this way

Answer (score 1):

```
let x =  Operation.UnaryOperation(factorial{if ($0<=1) {return 1} else {return $0 * factorial($0-1)}})
```

Comment: Would you explain it to me? why should I create a variable if it is in a dictionary? The "x!" is the string that is read from the button via currentTitle, and it's used to define what the button has to do

Comment: You should put some commentary with your answer to explain it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
func factorial(_ x: UInt) -> UInt {
    return x == 0 ? 1 : x * factorial(x - 1)
}

// Example:
print(factorial(6))
// 720
```